# When using Promise.all(),cannot read property 'then' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

error cannot read property 'then' of undefined :

```
getAll(id).then((resp) => {...} 
...
export function getAll(id){
    all([getOne(id), getTwo(id)]);  
}
...
export all(){
    return Promise.all([...arg])
}
```

I'don't know how to fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to return

```
export function getAll(id){
    return all([getOne(id), getTwo(id)]);  
}
```